# newenvironment with tcblisting

Tags: macros, listings, tcolorbox

I want to defne a macro environment that uses the `listings` and `tcolorbox` packages, something akin to this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newenvironment{codeblock}[1]
  {\begin{tcblisting}{title=#1}}
  {\end{tcblisting}}

\begin{document}
\begin{codeblock}
code
\end{codeblock}
\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

What do? I've tried searching around, but it seems to be a very general error message that has something to do with empty spaces in verbatim/listing environments.

I have tried implementing the code directly and it compiles. The error only arises when using the macro, and I'd much prefer using the macro considering I have a couple of hundred entries with the same formatting (not included for simplicity's sake).

Comment: Search for `\newtcblisting` in the [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the new listing format/style via `\newtcblisting`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\newtcblisting{codeblock}[1]{title=#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeblock}{code title}
code
\end{codeblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `\newtcblisting{codeblock}[2][]{title=#2,#1}` so that users could pass an optional argument to the environment containing per-block tweaks....?

Comment: @cmhughes: Good point. It's always nice to add some flexibility.